# how to define association in ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers, activemodel

I have following Serializer

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :publisher, :author, :cover_url
  has_many :chapters
end
```

I have two method in **bookscontroller.rb** file as follows:

```
def index
  books = Book.select(:id, :name, :publisher, :publisher, :cover, :author)
  if books.present?
    render json: books
  end
end

def show
  book = Book.find_by_id params[:id]
  render json: book
end
```

Actually everything is working fine but the problem is I want chapters records in show page not on index page, but right now query for fetching chapters are running in both action but I only want to include **has_many :chapters** in show action.

So Is there any way that can I use association for particular method in rails controller?

Comment: query for fetching chapters are running in both action, can you elaborate your understanding on this

Comment: actually in both actions index and show there is query to fetch chapters, but I want to fetch chapters for show action not on index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different serializers for different actions. For example, remove `has_many :chapters` from BookSerializer and create a separate `BookWithChaptersSerializer`. Use it as follows:

```
class BookWithChaptersSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :publisher, :author, :cover_url
  has_many :chapters
end

def show
  book = Book.find_by_id params[:id]
  render json: book, serializer: BookWithChaptersSerializer
end
```